# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." Django DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, drf-spectacular

Im trying to create an api for my django project to get some data from database and show it as restframework `Response`

everytime I try to get the data it shows me this error
[image]

this is my `views.py` code for getting the data

```
class QuestionListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self: Self, request: HttpRequest) -> Response:
        questions_list: Question = Question.objects.filter(status=True)
        if (len(questions_list) == 0):
            return Response('هنوز سوالی طرح نشده', status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        else:
            serializer = QuestionsSerializer(instance=questions_list, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

this is my question model `models.py` file

```
class Question(models.Model):
    CHOISES: list = [
        ('option1', 'گزینه اول'),
        ('option2', 'گزینه دوم'),
        ('option3', 'گزینه سوم'),
        ('option4', 'گزینه چهارم'),
    ]
    
    SCALES: list = [
        (1, 'آسان'),
        (2, 'متوسط'),
        (3, 'سخت'),
    ]
    
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name='سوال')
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='گزینه اول')
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='گزینه دوم')
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='گزینه سوم')
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='گزینه چهارم')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOISES, verbose_name='پاسخ', help_text='گزینه درست را انتخاب کنید')
    scale = models.IntegerField(choices=SCALES ,null=True, verbose_name='سطح سختی سوال')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='وضعیت انتشار سوال', verbose_name='وضعیت')

    def __str__(self):
        super(Question, self).__str__()
        return self.question

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'سوال'
        verbose_name_plural = 'سوالات'
```

and this is the `serializer.py` file

```
class QuestionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        exclude = ('status',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

and this is my `settings.py` file

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_h%&8dv!_+zqct3*f*w3$5z*+ca#^jxmx^ze1i+r^f&a3k5f$x'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jazzmin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'account_app.apps.AccountAppConfig',
    'quiz_app.apps.QuizAppConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'QuizApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'QuizApp.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# برای فارسی سازی کد زیر رو آن کامنت کن

# LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa-ir'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'shervin2234@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your password here'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}

# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
#        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
#    ),
#    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
#         'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
#    ),
# }

# تنظیمات مرتبط با Spectacular API

SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'Your Project API',
    'DESCRIPTION': 'Your project description',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
}
```

I actually don't know what to do and I would be really thankful if you help me

Answer (score 2):

Its happening because you are using

> permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] in your **QuestionListView**

You must provide the auth token. For example you can use the [Mobheader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader-modify-http-hea/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=pl) extension.

> 

or if authorization is not needed, change:

> permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

to:

> permission_classes = [AllowAny]